# SQL - Dynamic way to pass column names from a list

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, dynamic

I have a table where I store column `namea` which looks something like this :

```
header
Ref_1
Ref_4
Ref_6
Ref_100
```

I want to run a dynamic sql which will use the values above table as column names which should look like this :

```
select mycolumn1, mycolumn2 a from mytable1 b inner join a.ref = **b.ref_1**
select mycolumn1, mycolumn2 a from mytable1 b inner join a.ref = **b.ref_4**
select mycolumn1, mycolumn2 a from mytable1 b inner join a.ref = **b.ref_6**
select mycolumn1, mycolumn2 a from mytable1 b inner join a.ref = **b.ref_100**
```

here you see b.ref_{#} should be pass dynamically, is there any way I do this ?

I can do this easily using C# script or SQL Server Integration services, but I would like to do this in T_SQL ?

thanks in advance

Comment: Your select statement is not correct? Missing table `a` in the from clause.

Comment: Do you need script for all columns for for a particular column?

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @str varchar(max) = (
   select 'select mycolumn1, mycolumn2 a from mytable1 b inner join a.ref = b. ' + your_column_table.header
   from your_column_table
)
```

then you can execute the @str

If you want to generate separate sql statement, you need to loop over your_column_table and do the same thing

Comment: While flickers approach would do the trick, the preferred approach would be to use sp_execute_sql.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to loop over and run a query for each column name you can try the below query:

```
DECLARE @q nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @ctr INT

SELECT @ctr= COUNT(1) FROM mytable1

WHILE (@ctr>0)
BEGIN

   SELECT @q= 
       'select mycolumn1, mycolumn2 a from mytable1 b inner join a.ref = b.' + 
         namea 
    FROM (
          SELECT namea, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY namea ASC) AS R 
          FROM mytable1 
         ) T WHERE R=@ctr

  SET @ctr=@ctr-1
  EXEC(@q)
END
```

Sample Output is below
[image]